# saving name,value pairs from req.request into a file

Tags: node.js

I would like to be able to save the name value pairs in req.query the same way as shown in console.log (as shown below).  So far I got [object object] when I tried to save the content of req.query into a file.  Can someone help me.  Thanks!

```
    console.log(req.query)

    { field1: 'employee_id',
      field2: 'first',
      field3: 'last',
      field4: 'email',
      format: 'CSV',
      type1: 'numerical',
      type2: 'text',
      type3: 'text',
      type4: 'email' }
```

My code for save the req.query:

```
   fs.writeFile("./data/client_data", req.query, function(err) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("The file was saved!");
   });
```

Comment: Try stringifying it : `JSON.stringify(req.query)` before saving.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your suggestion worked beautifully.